# Mean Square Error in Python from scratch from equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to find the mse for a given Phi, with output y, and calculated weights w. While trying to implement (y - w(transpose) * Phi ) in w(transpose) * Phi  i am getting Value error. I know this is dimension error, but I've tried to change it and its not working for me.

I've tried transpose (but its not really transposing, just stays as it is), and reshape.

```
X=[1,2,3]
d=3
Phi=np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander(X,d)
y=[2,3,4]

def train_model(Phi, y):
 pht = np.matrix.transpose(Phi)
 u = np.matmul(pht,Phi)
 q = np.linalg.inv(u)
 s = np.matmul(q,pht)
 w = np.matmul(s,y)
 return w
w=train_model(Phi,y)

def evaluate_model(Phi, y, w):
    sum=0
    wt = np.matrix.transpose(w)
    for i in range (0,len(y)):
        g = np.matmul(wt,Phi[:,i])
        k = y[i]-g
        l = k ** 2
        sum+=l
    avg=sum/len(y)   
    return avg
```

Edit:

The error I get is

```
ValueError: shapes (4,) and (53,) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 53 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Check your indentation. Especially in `evaluate_model()`

Comment: It looks like your indexing is wrong, try `g = np.matmul(wt,Phi[i,:])`

I'm assuming the indentation errors are only here in stackoverflow and your actual code is correct

Comment: @Tacratis please do not edit code; while your assumptions on their indentation is *probably* correct, you cannot be sure it is actually what the OP has written.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds it was my understanding that edits are first going through the person who posted the question for confirmation - do they actually go live even before he confirms them?

Comment: @Tacratis ah, yes you have the wrong impression. They get reviewed by other SO members and do go live once they receive a confirmation from two users, or one user with high enough rep. On the top right navigation on SO, you'll see a checklist icon---that's the edit review queue, which you can go into and help validate edits and new posts, and it gives you a walkthrough. Sorry to OP for this discussion on their post.

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? What line is that happening on? The problem is that you're trying to operate a length-4 array with a length 53-array. It is unclear what arrays have those shapes and what you're trying to do with them---if you need to broadcast then you simply need to reshape one of them into a column vector (that is, a (N, 1) array instead of an (N,) array). @Tacratis mentioned the possibility of swapped indices---does that fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indexing is wrong, try

```
g = np.matmul(wt,Phi[i,:])
```